# Hide a normal share when the share is already under DFS share?

Tags: network-share, file-sharing, dfs, windows-server-2016

I'm wondering if it is possible to hide the normal windows file server share when that same share has been published via DFS on the same server?

To clarify, say I'm running DFS on a server called FILESVR and there are 3 folder in it's storage that I want to share, (e.g. HR, Sales, Marketing). DFS is running on Server 2016, AD integrated with 2008 mode active. Domain controllers are hosted elsewhere.

Anyway, when I share the folders using DFS, it creates normal file shares AND shortcuts inside the DFS namespace, which as you can guess, is unnecessarily redundant and also confusing for a lot of end users. Have a look at the attached figure to see what I mean:

[DFS Share example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehQdX.jpg)

The DFS Namespace is "OfficeData" and inside it has shares for HR, Marketing and Sales. However, they are also shown up in the server root as normal shares. I don't want that. I want the folder to show up under DFS only and not on the file server root.

I understand I can use a separate server for Namespace which will solve the issue but then again, I don't want to have a separate sever just for that.

I have also read that the $ shares also doesn't work or has other issues therefore I haven't checked it out yet.

So, is there a way to achieve this?

Any help is appreciated.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try sharing the folder with a $ sing in the end

```
sharename$
```

Answer (score 1):

If these folders are child folders under the OfficeData share then you don't need to share these child folders. They're accessible via the parent share.

Stop sharing these child folders and your problem will be solved.

Comment: OfficeData is the namespace, not the share. The actual shares are the folders under Officedata. And @Str82DHeaD seems to be right about $ shares. I checked it out later and it was working fine so far.